# Where does MFC COleControl::DoPropExchange store persistent properties?

Tags: c++, mfc, persistence, ocx

I have taken over maintenance of a legacy MFC OCX control in C++. The project is now in VS2013.  I'm trying to understand the functioning of the DoPropExchange method.  This method appears to be calling PX_?????(member) for nearly all the data members in the control where ???? is the type (Bool, Short, Long ...) My understanding is these are called for the purpose of providing persistent storage of properties.  But from my understanding of the operation of the OCX control there are no persistent properties.  Would there be any other reason to be calling PX_???? for all data members in DoPropExchange other than to support persistent properties?  I'm also trying to understand where these persistent properties are loaded/stored.  Where is the serialized file for loading/storing persistent property values specified?

Here is the source for DoPropExchange

```
// CSigPlusCtrl::DoPropExchange - Persistence support
void CSigPlusCtrl::DoPropExchange(CPropExchange* pPX)
{
    DWORD Version;
    long BaudRate;
    short ComPort;
    BOOL Rv;

    LOG(("DoPropExchange Entry"));

    ExchangeVersion(pPX, MAKELONG(_wVerMinor, _wVerMajor));
    COleControl::DoPropExchange(pPX);
    Version = pPX->GetVersion();

    if (pPX->IsLoading())
    {
        LoadDefaultProperties();
        LoadIniParameters();
    }

    if ((Version & 0xFFFF0000) == (DWORD)MAKELONG(0, _wVerMajor))
    {
        Rv = PX_Short(pPX, _T("ImageFileFormat"), ImageFileFormat, 0);
        Rv = PX_Short(pPX, _T("ImageXSize"), ImageXSize, 0);
        Rv = PX_Short(pPX, _T("ImageYSize"), ImageYSize, 0);
        Rv = PX_Short(pPX, _T("ImagePenWidth"), ImagePenWidth, 1);
   . . .
        Rv = PX_Short(pPX, _T("ZoomY"), ZoomY, 0);
        Rv = PX_Short(pPX, _T("ZoomPower"), ZoomPower, 1);

        if (pPX->IsLoading())
        {
            if (SigBlob != NULL)
            {
                GlobalFree(SigBlob);
                SigBlob = NULL;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (SigBlob == NULL)
            {
                SigBlobType* SigBlobPtr;

                SigBlob = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, sizeof(DWORD));
                SigBlobPtr = (SigBlobType*)GlobalLock(SigBlob);
                SigBlobPtr->Size = 0;
                GlobalUnlock(SigBlob);
            }
        }

        if ((Version & 0xFFFF) == Version223)
        {
            Rv = PX_Blob(pPX, _T("SigBlob"), SigBlob, NULL);
        }
        if ((Version & 0xFFFF) >= Version224)
        {
            CString SigStr;

            if (!pPX->IsLoading())
            {
                SigStr = BlobToString();
            }
            Rv = PX_String(pPX, _T("SigStringStored"), SigStr, _T(""));
            if (pPX->IsLoading())
            {
                BlobFromString(SigStr);
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        SigMessageBox("Warning Incompatable Versions of SigPlus Control");
    }
    LoadTabletParameters();
    LOG(("DoPropExchange Exit"));
}
```

EDIT Added 6-21-2018

Running in the debugger I observe that when DoPropExchange is called, VS2013 shows the stack with a message that stack frames below may be incorrect.  And the one frame just above, that calls DoPropExchange, is from mfc120d.dll which does not have symbol file available mfc120d.i386.pdb.
[image]

This [Microsoft Forum Post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eca49b7c-76d7-406f-96ac-dcdca5e35d4a/mfc140di386pdb-could-not-be-found-in-the-selected-paths?forum=vsdebug) seems to indicate that the symbol file is not available for VS2015 and I'm wondering if that is also the case for VS2013.  So far I have not been able to find place to download MFC120 symbols for debug.

Starting a bounty today to find someone who can explain how and where properties are normally serialized for OLE controls and what methods are used to specify the serialized data storage location/media.  This is of concern because this control runs in a Citrix ZenDesk network environment in a Terminal Aware program and if properties are being stored somewhere then each client needs to specify a location unique to that client.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Clearly, you *are* calling `COleControl::DoPropExchange(pPX)`, so you *are* serializing the base class' persistent properties. You are also serializing custom properties. Why do you assume, that there were no persistent properties? I don't know, whether you are using the serialization support for anything but persisting information. But it could be used to marshal control state across apartments as well. I'm not saying that this is happening, but streams can represent more than just files on a disk.

Comment: "Why do you assume there are no persistent properties..."
Because I know the operation of the OCX control from the use case and it has no properties that persist.  I'm trying to understand if the code above is trying to store properties somewhere and if so where.  Or is it simply being used to load the default values at startup.  This is a legacy OCX and exclusively uses an INI file with no use of the registry.  The INI file does not get altered when OCX is executed.  So if it is trying to persist properties it's a mystery as to where those values are stored.

Comment: It's unclear, why you believe that knowing *where* the data is stored would help you understand the code. It clearly *is* storing persistent data (e.g. `ImageFileFormat`). If you want to learn more about your code, run it under a debugger, set breakpoints/tracepoints, and so on. The question you asked does not appear to get you closer to your goal, which, apparently is, understanding your code.

Comment: The values for all properties for the control are either set by hard coded values in the LoadDefaultProperties() method or read from the INI file in a method called LoadIniProperties.  Any calls from the container app that modify properties are not persisted across control instances or system reboot.  And the OCX control does not write back any values to the INI files.  So I'm trying to understand why the original developer created a DoPropExchange that appears to be loading/storing properties.

Comment: I have run the code in debugger extensively.  The challenge is that the call to DoPropExchange comes from the MFC framework and at present VS2013 isn't allowing me to step into or trace into callers MFC code.  So at this point what's happening before the call to DoPropExchange and after the call to PX_Short/Long etc is not accessible.

Comment: That question can only be answered by the original developer. If they were kind enough, they left enough documentation to follow their rationale. If done properly, your SCM will also hold several answers.

Comment: Unfortunately the original developer is no longer available and there is no internal documentation on this method.  So exploring in debugger and inquiring here are my options at this point.  And as stated in my original question, one of the mysteries is where is this being stored because having worked with this OCX for a year now from the container side I see no evidence of property persistence.

Comment: I'm thinking what would be helpful is a link to a description or tutorial on DoPropExchange that explains the purpose and function.  Things like what is the pPX object, how exactly do the PX_type functions work and what are Blobs, what is their purpose and how do they work.

Comment: There is documentation: [MFC ActiveX Controls: Serializing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-activex-controls-serializing). Same goes for the `PX_` functions. Other than that, you have full access to MFC's source code.

Comment: I've read the link  you mention and it still does not describe how or where the serialized data is stored or how that location is specified.  I've also looked at the PX_???? documentation and neither does it describe where the serialized variables are read from and/or written to.   As an experiment I just removed all code from the DoPropExchange() method and rebuilt the OCX.  I see no observable difference in operational behavior.   So this tends to confirm that the code in this DoPropExchange() is not functional.  But I'm still looking for someone who can tell me where the serialized file is.

Comment: You still have the source code. It's unclear, why you cannot simply debug into it, inspect the call stack, identify, where the target stream gets created, and work your way towards finding the information you are looking for. It's not immediately clear to me, what you hope to gain from finding out, *where* the data is serialized to, though.

Comment: @IInspectable See EDIT added to question 6-21-18

Comment: You have disabled downloading symbol data from Microsoft's symbol server. Why?

Comment: Thanks.  I had not noticed that there is a checkbox that must be checked.  However it was already in the unchecked state.  I didn't deselect it. Curious why VS2013 defaulted this to "unchecked".   I am now able to load the mfc120.dll symbols.  However I am still looking for answer to original question on where serialized properties are stored and what method/methods are used to specify the location.

Answer (score 0):

The DoPropExchange is used to implement control attribute persistence mainly between design and run-time. The actual destination sink is passed by the client of the OCX.

In VC the the settings are stored in RC file while in VB in frm and frx files. If you open FRM in notepad you would probably see the section with the properties of this control.
As a side note, there is a similar implementation in case the control is used in HTML with inline settings in he html itself.

Unless your VB clients saves the settings externally via direct calls to Property bag function it is not likely you have a issue here since the above properties are not stored at runtime.

Comment: I'm still not understanding.  The OCX is in C++.   You say the the property values are stored in the .rc file.  But the .rc file is not available at run-time.  You say destination sink is passed by client.  Where? how?  I don't see any calls to do this.    There is no parameter to support this passed when OCX is instantiated in the VB client.
Set m_ZoomSigPlus2 = CreateObject("SIGPLUS.SigPlusCtrl.1")

Comment: The CreateObject example does not in fact pass anything to your component. However, this is not how VB form initializes the child controls.
The  interfaces that are actually used by your clients are IPersistStream, IPersistStorage, IpersistPropertyBag. The MFC implementation adapts the call and invokes the DoPropertyExchange. 
See the following link ftp://fpc.org/fpc32/VS6Disk1/VC98/MFC/SRC/CTLPBAG.CPP for MFC implementation of  IpersistPropertyBag

Comment: There are no calls to IPersistStream, IPersistStorage, IPersistProperyBag or DoProperyExchange in the VB Client.  

I have experience using data exchange with MFC Dialog Windows and in that case I understand what is being exchanged.  The data for a class member variable associated with a given control in the dialog is being exchanged with the underlying Windows control.   In this case however I am not understanding what the two endpoints of the data exchange are.  One is the data members of the OCX control class but I haven't heard an explanation of what the other end of the exchange is.

Comment: It comes down to this, when I run the OCX in VS Debugger I see that DoPropExchange is calling PX_type for each data member in the OCX class, but I don't see where the data is coming from or going to when this exchange is done at run-time in the field.  Nor do I see any calls in the VB client that specify where this data retrieved from or stored to.